# How is measured BRDF data recorded?

Tags: raytracing, pathtracing, brdf, pbr

How is measured BRDF data recorded? Like the [MERL BRDF Database](https://www.merl.com/brdf/).

What kind of equipment is used and what are the key values that need to be recorded?

I know one place this data was used was in the [Disney PBR paper](https://disney-animation.s3.amazonaws.com/library/s2012_pbs_disney_brdf_notes_v2.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Section 6 of [Microfacet Models for Refraction through Rough Surfaces](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~srm/publications/EGSR07-btdf.html) has a good description of how they did it to validate their own model. That may not be everything needed to build a full database (eg. more automation) but it's an interesting read.